# Rails each do undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i have checked and there is no CSS text-transform: uppercase , in all My HTML or CSS docs.. but just when i use this "each loop" i get Uppercase in the name of the country.. and just in the name of the country..

I have look in a lot of questions, but i cant found a similar problem on anybody, what im getting uppercase.

EDIT: I just clear cache and reload, actually there is not uppercase, there is A ERROR

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

```
 <% @player.citizens.each do |citizen| %>

          <%= t('generales.citizen') %> :
          <%= citizen.country.name %>

    <% end %>
```

Ok here are some models,

Country.rb

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iso, :name, :printable_name, :iso3, :numcode
end
```

Citizen.rb

```
class Citizen < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :country_id

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :country

end
```

Club.rb

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :division, :from, :to, :country_id

  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :country

  DIVISION = %w{
    first_division
    second_division
    third_division
    amateur_division
  }

  YEARS = (1950..(Time.now.strftime('%Y')).to_i).to_a

end
```

Ok also this code is working fine (clubs)

```
 <% @player.clubs.each do |club| %>
  <% if club.name.present? %>
    <p>
      <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.name' %> :
      <%= club.name %><br />
      <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.country' %> :
      <%= club.country.name %><br />
      <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.division' %> :
      <%= t "generales.#{club.division}" if club.division.present? %><br />
      <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.from' %>
      <%= club.from %>
      <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.club.to' %>
      <%= club.to %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you execute that code apart from HTML, is it uppercased? Have you looked at the `country` and `name` methods?

Comment: You should post more relevant code. Is the `name` method custom or just the accessor provided? Can you post the relevant css or picture of the page that could help us visualize? It seems that this could should just print out the name.

Comment: Sorry im modifying an app im noob in rails, where can i found the method? they are in models ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
<% @player.citizens.each do |citizen| %>

      <%= t('generales.citizen') %> :
      <%= citizen.country.name.titleize  # This Will Make The First Letter Of Each Word A Cap %>
      <%= citizen.country.name.downcase # this will make every letter lowercase %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Im really sorry, the uppercase dissapear when i clear cache, i realized then there is an error, cause just then it was printed undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass .. But i do really appreciate